# How to change the width of "yAxis label" in HighChart?

Tags: css, highcharts

I am working on a multiple chart which looks like this:
[image]

And I found HighCharts may be the best source for my purpose.
Then I have a chart looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bardirian/7cpzxeth/1/show

As you can see in the JSFiddle, the width of "yAxis label" is not aligned.

This is what I tried, but not working:

```
g.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-yaxis-labels text {
  width:100px!important;
}
```

Can somebody help to make all the "yaxis-labels" display with 100px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `chart.marginLeft` [API Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginLeft)

```
  chart: {
      type: 'scatter',
      plotBorderWidth: 3,
      zoomType: 'xy',
      backgroundColor:null,
      marginLeft:80
  },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cpzxeth/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is perfect!